# Enforcing URL trailing slashes for mounted engines in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have an engine called `Battalion` mounted into my host application like so:

```
mount Battalion::Engine => '/@:site_username'
```

The `Battalion` engine is conceptually a different website than the host application; it has separate assets, etc. The problem I am encountering has to do with trailing slashes. When I visit the route `http://localhost:3000/@jon` I want to be redirected to the **same** route but with a trailing slash, like `http://localhost:3000/@jon/`.

This is important because I want to use relative URLs for assets once the user is in the engine.

I am aware of the `trailing_slash` option that can be applied to link helpers, but I want to enforce the redirection at the controller level, and not for each link. I also read a [blog post](http://www.jumph4x.net/post/16395866916/ensuring-a-trailing-slash-in-rails-w-out-dependencies) that offered a good solution, but it breaks in my particular case because I am using the `:site_username` variable within my route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the best way to handle this is a slight modification of the answer found in [this post](http://www.jumph4x.net/post/16395866916/ensuring-a-trailing-slash-in-rails-w-out-dependencies). His advice isn't quite applicable in this case because there is a parameter embedded in the URL to the engine. Here's the solution I found:

In the `application_controller.rb` of the engine:

```
def ensure_trailing_slash
  redirect_to url_for(params = :trailing_slash => true), :status => 301 unless trailing_slash?
end

def trailing_slash?
  request.env['REQUEST_URI'].match(/[^\?]+/).to_s.last == '/'
end
```

In the controller that contains the root path:

```
before_filter :ensure_trailing_slash, :only => :index
```